# Discord.js - DiscordAPIError[50013]: Missing Permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I created a discord bot, using Discord.js, that removes a message if it detects a link. However, I only want it to do this on some channels of a server, not on everything. So I took away his permission to manage messages on some channels.
When I send a link on one of the channels where the bot doesn't have permission to delete the message, it stops working, giving me this error (related to the delete):

> rawError: { message: 'Missing Permissions', code: 50013 },
> code: 50013,
> status: 403,
> method: 'DELETE',
> requestBody: { files: undefined, json: undefined }*

The part of the code related to the problem is this:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
  ]
});

client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
  if (msg.content.match(regex)) {
    msg.delete();
  }
})
```

I also tried with a try catch, but it didn't fix the problem.

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're getting is telling you exactly what's wrong: You removed the bot's permissions in specific channels, and you're trying to perform an action in those channels that the bot doesn't have permission to do.

This seems like more of a design problem than a debugging problem. My recommendation would be to persist a list of channel IDs for channels you *do* want your bot to delete messages in somewhere, then check the `message.channel.id` property when a new message is created and ensure it's in your list of channel IDs. Messages have a [channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=channel) property which have an [id property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=id) you can key off of.

To get a channel's ID, you will need to turn on Developer Mode (User Settings -> Advanced -> Developer Mode) and right click a channel, selecting "Copy ID" for use in your code.

Here's how I would do that, put simply:

```
// Example Channel IDs that we want our bot to delete messages in,
// yours will be different
const channelIDs = ['222222222222222222', '333333333333333333'];

client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
  if (msg.content.match(regex) && channelIDs.includes(msg.channel.id)) {
    msg.delete();
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked and it's the one for me, since I have to make personal use of the bot.
But what if the bot were to be made accessible to multiple users who want to do the same thing? I could not know all the channel IDs of all servers where the bot will be added.

Comment: @FrancescoCastiglione You would need to write commands that users can utilize to register specific channels as channels to be watched. You would need to store those channel IDs somewhere, and check against them when your bot detects that a message was created. In other words, you need to give your users a way to register channels themselves.